# Meaning of a ubiquitous sentence in patents

Tags: meaning-in-context

I noticed this sentence in many patents:

> *Other objects of the invention will in part be obvious and will in part appear hereinafter.*

What exactly are the authors trying to say by "be obvious"?

For examples of how much this sentence can be found, search for ["other objects of the invention will in part"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22other%20objects%20of%20the%20invention%20will%20in%20part%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t) (even in quotes, it returns over 1 million hits).

Comment: It is obvious what the sentence means. What need not be explained is ignored and the rest discussed below.

Comment: Btw, you mean ambiguous sentence, not ubiquitous.

Comment: @Kris No, I mean ubiquitous, given that it occurs in so many patents.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Obvious* does have its usual meaning:

> *adjective*
>
> - easily perceived or understood; clear, self-evident, or apparent
>
> [[ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obvious?q=obvious)]

A quirk of patent law is that obvious things cannot be patented. The sentence is saying that everything about the invention is either *obvious* (and therefore not patentable) or *included in the application* and therefore part of the patent.

What the sentence does is limit the patent to what is explicitly stated in the application, **and** by saying that everything else is "obvious", seek to stop anyone else applying for a patent for the invention based on some other benefit not listed.

Comment: +1 Good answer. However, that makes the question 'Too-localized'.

Comment: @Kris is `ask patents` better forum for this question then?

Comment: @user13107: Time will tell if this question is really too localized or too obvious. Sometimes one close vote is just the start of many others; other times, the person casting the first close vote is in the steadfast minority, and the question stays open. That's why it takes five votes to close a question. I found this question rather interesting, to be honest.

Comment: I learned something about patents from the question. So, that's something.